# Error /.zprofile:3 and /.zprofile:4 message every time I open Terminal after installing Homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I am very new. I just signed up for a coding bootcamp and installed Homebrew to my MacBookAir (montereyOS). I followed the installation steps correctly and when I typed `brew doctor` I received the correct message of `Your system is ready to brew.`

The problem is that every time I open my terminal, I'm greeted by this message

```
/Users/MYNAME/.zprofile:3: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/MYNAME/.zprofile:4: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

Would anyone be able to advise me on how to remove this? Or if I did something incorrectly.

I tried downloading Homebrew again to confirm that I didn't omit or misspell anything the first time. But it the message continues.

Comment: Is your mac an intel or Apple silicon mac? (You can check in the about this mac window in the apple menu). Also is there any chance that you chose to install homebrew to a location other than where it puts itself by default?